# Deploying Custom theme in production server

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I'm working on a Liferay project.

I'm developing a new `Liferay theme` using `Plugins SDK`.

I wonder is it better to use `ANT or MAVEN` for the project?

Because I managed to run both projects in eclipse.

Also is there any way to deploy automatically the theme in the production server ?  (Distant server using tomcat).

For now I'm just using auto deployment, copying the war file to the /deploy file.

Regards

Comment: Is ant or maven better? "It depends". At least both are different. Also, I personally object to be able to deploy new plugins to a production server "on the fly" from a development environment. It's a bit too fragile IMHO. Do you have a proper backup? Can you reproduce the current server setup on a new machine, should the current one go down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add remote server to your Eclipse with Plugins SDK, check https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/developing-apps-with-liferay-ide-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-02-en

Answer (score 0):

(this may be helpful for older versions of plugins-sdk)

Assuming that you have ssh access to the remote server, the following ant target can be added and used in `/liferay-plugins-sdk/build-common-plugin.xml`

```
<property name="web-server" value="11.11.11.11" />
<property name="web-server-username" value="yourusername" />
<property name="web-server-password" value="yourpassword" />
<property name="web-server-deploy-folder-path" value="/liferay-x.x/deploy" />

<target name="remote-deploy" depends="war">
    <echo message="Copying plugin to remote server ..." />
    <scp
        file="${plugin.file}"
        todir="${web-server-username}:${web-server-password}@${web-server}:${web-server-deploy-folder-path}" 
        trust="true"
      />
    <echo message="Done!" />
</target>
```

Comment: Hi This worked for me as well, but its more comfortable to use the remote server adapter for managing deployment.